# While loop always ending one loop early

Tags: c++, linked-list

What seems to be happening here is that my while loop ends 1 loop early every time. It is set so that it will keep going until t->next is NULL. although it always stopped one early, even though the ->next pointer is indeed pointing to something. Here is the code. I have all the formal declarations and other things done in other parts of my code, so I won't post them here to keep it simple

```
int job_allocated(const int job)
{
  ALLOCPTR t = alloclist;


  int sizeofjob = 0;


  while(t->next!=NULL)
  {

    if(t->id==job)
    {

        sizeofjob=sizeofjob+t->size;
    }

    cout << t << endl;
    cout << t->id << endl;
    cout << t->next << endl;
    t=t->next;

}
```

here is the output

```
0x600010540
2
0x600010520
0x600010520
3
0x600010500
0x600010500
2
0x6000104e0
```

As you can see the ->next pointer does indeed point to memory, but for some reason the while loop ends right after, instead of running one more time.

In my `main` I have 4 Jobs that I have allocated, yet the loop will not go to the last one.

Comment: Since you seem to want to go until, *and including*, the last node in the list, is there some special reason you're not using `while (t != NULL)` (which coincidentally also prevents an initial null dereference on an empty list) ? If your answer is "because I push an initial sentinel node I need to ignore", *don't*. The value `NULL` is a fine sentinel that says "I'm empty."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be `while (t != NULL)`. If you write `while (t->text != NULL)` you both open yourself up to undefined behavior for an empty list, and cause the loop to not process `t` when `t` points to the last node (remember, if `t` points to the last node, then `t->next` is `NULL`, and the loop will not run).

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would be very obvious but I just could not figure it out!